# Reusing JPA annotated class in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails

I followed the documentation and put my JPA annotated classes under `src/main/java`.

In addition I put a `hibernate.cfg.xml` under `conf/hibernate` which looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping package="com.damluar" />
        <mapping class="com.damluar.CustomerPropertyEntity"/>
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I also found mentions that I need to add

```
configClass = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsAnnotationConfiguration
```

to my `DataSource.groovy`.

Then I generated controllers and views using scaffolding. When I start the app or use a `console`, Grails throws exception:

```
URI
    /dataTypeEntity/index
Class
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
    No signature of method: static com.damluar.DataTypeEntity.count() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), wait(), dump(), collect(), find()
```

It looks like Grails doesn't add persistence methods to the domain classes.

Also when I start the application Grails lists existing artefacts:
Artefacts

```
Controllers: 3
Domains: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Grails 3.0.1, and the solution was to put `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `grails-app/conf` (not inside a hibernate subdirectory) as described in [mapping-with-hibernate-annotations-in-grails-3-0-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830155/mapping-with-hibernate-annotations-in-grails-3-0-1).