# Mapping with Hibernate Annotations in Grails 3.0.1

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-3.0

How can I map a domain class with annotations in Grails 3.0.1?

The following steps didn't work for me.

**Step 1**. I have created a new application with Grails 3.0.1 (`grails create-app books`).

**Step 2**. As described in [Mapping with Hibernate Annotations](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html#mappingWithHibernateAnnotations) I have created a new class in `src/main/com/books/Book.groovy` (tried `src/main/groovy/com/books/Book.groovy` as well)

```
package com.books;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date date;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Step 3**. Then registered the class with the Hibernate sessionFactory by adding relevant entries to the `grails-app/conf/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml` file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping package="com.books" />
        <mapping class="com.books.Book" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Step 4**. After starting the application (`grails run-app`), the 'Welcome to Grails' page (`grails-app/views/index.gsp`) reports zero domain classes, which means the mapping didn't take effect:

- grails run-app
- Load localhost:8080
- Notice the 'Domains: 0' under the section 'ARTEFACTS'

### Relevant exception in Grails 3.0.1

If I query the above domain class, the following exception is thrown

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Book is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
       .hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:332) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3678) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `grails-app/conf` (not inside a hibernate subdirectory)

Comment: Yes, putting hibernate.cfg.xml in grails-app/conf instead of grails-app/conf/hibernate does the trick. Thank you Graeme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Graeme suggested, the solution is putting `hibernate.cfg.xml` in `grails-app/conf` instead of `grails-app/conf/hibernate`, otherwise the configuration will not take effect. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/pull/270) to reflect this in the [relevant documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/hibernate.html#mappingWithHibernateAnnotations) and I hope the update to take effect soon so to prevent other users from facing the same issue.